# Trying to create a new job via the rest api

Tags: jenkins

How do you create a new job via the rest api using json. I can do it via xml but i can't seem to do it via JSON.

http://localhost:9080/createItem/api/ is meant to give me a sample of what i need to submit, but it just says it needs to be a post, when i try to post, it keeps saying no mode given, but i can't find any documentation on what mode is and what a an acceptable answer.

===Duplicating as it didn't meet standards befor ei could submit===
http://localhost:9080/createItem/api/ is meant to give me a sample of what i need to submit, but it just says it needs to be a post, when i try to post, it keeps saying no mode given, but i can't find any documentation on what mode is and what a an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Jenkins jobs by posting JSON. It only works by posting XML.

Comment: ah ok, do you know how to check which endpoint can be created by JSON and which can't, is it basically any endpoint that has the api website?